# No tags being created

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, terraform, devops

As I'm new to terraform I'm creating a very simple piece of code to create an EC2 instance with tags on AWS:

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-2"
}

resource "aws_instance" "assignment2" {
    ami = "ami-06dc09bb8854cbde3"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags = {
        Name = "test"
    }
}
```

Its currently creating the EC2 instance but not adding the tags. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing please. Thank you.

EDIT: The current output (that shows no tags are being added by terraform) is:

Terraform will perform the following actions:

```
  # aws_instance.example will be created
  + resource "aws_instance" "example" {
      + ami                                  = "ami-06dc09bb8854cbde3"
      + arn                                  = (known after apply)
      + associate_public_ip_address          = (known after apply)
      + availability_zone                    = (known after apply)
      + cpu_core_count                       = (known after apply)
      + cpu_threads_per_core                 = (known after apply)
      + get_password_data                    = false
      + host_id                              = (known after apply)
      + id                                   = (known after apply)
      + instance_initiated_shutdown_behavior = (known after apply)
      + instance_state                       = (known after apply)
      + instance_type                        = "t2.micro"
      + ipv6_address_count                   = (known after apply)
      + ipv6_addresses                       = (known after apply)
      + key_name                             = (known after apply)
      + outpost_arn                          = (known after apply)
      + password_data                        = (known after apply)
      + placement_group                      = (known after apply)
      + primary_network_interface_id         = (known after apply)
      + private_dns                          = (known after apply)
      + private_ip                           = (known after apply)
      + public_dns                           = (known after apply)
      + public_ip                            = (known after apply)
      + secondary_private_ips                = (known after apply)
      + security_groups                      = (known after apply)
      + source_dest_check                    = true
      + subnet_id                            = (known after apply)
      + tags_all                             = (known after apply)
      + tenancy                              = (known after apply)
      + vpc_security_group_ids               = (known after apply)

      + ebs_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + snapshot_id           = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }

      + enclave_options {
          + enabled = (known after apply)
        }

      + ephemeral_block_device {
          + device_name  = (known after apply)
          + no_device    = (known after apply)
          + virtual_name = (known after apply)
        }

      + metadata_options {
          + http_endpoint               = (known after apply)
          + http_put_response_hop_limit = (known after apply)
          + http_tokens                 = (known after apply)
        }

      + network_interface {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_index          = (known after apply)
          + network_interface_id  = (known after apply)
        }

      + root_block_device {
          + delete_on_termination = (known after apply)
          + device_name           = (known after apply)
          + encrypted             = (known after apply)
          + iops                  = (known after apply)
          + kms_key_id            = (known after apply)
          + tags                  = (known after apply)
          + throughput            = (known after apply)
          + volume_id             = (known after apply)
          + volume_size           = (known after apply)
          + volume_type           = (known after apply)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the correct instance?

Comment: When we check on AWS Console , tag comes in a different section . Tags should have been created , your code seems correct. Could you please recheck . May be run again with some unique name and region .

Comment: @Marcin I only have one instance (the one I'm creating) as I have just the practice free tier account and destroy each time I create the instances

Comment: @Deepali Mittal I'm checking the section under 'Tags'. I assume this is the right section?

Comment: When you run terraform do you see any warning or error. Does the credentials used by the automation has create tags permission.

Comment: @DeepaliMittal What's the best way to go about checking permissions? I added a custom policy with the "ec2:CreateTags" action as well as using ec2 full access policy.

Answer (score 1):

check syntax of tags

1. In tag name, 'N' should be capital (eg. Name = "instance")
2. go to configuration file and edit at tag.
3. check file name whether it is saved  with .tf extension

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was saving the file as txt instead of tf. Apparently it can still create the instance but it can't create the tags! I think this shows how much of a beginner I am with terraform lol.